# How to set generic properties with LINQ selector

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, expression

I have multiple queries that look like this:

```
var query = from a in EntityAs
            select new EntityASmall()
            {
                // Common Stuff:
                Id = a.Id,
                Name = a.Name,
                ShortName = a.ShortName,
                // Specific to EntityA:
                ASpecificProperty1 = a.1,
                ASpecificProperty2 = a.2
            };

var query = from b in EntityBs
            select new EntityBSmall()
            {
                // Common Stuff:
                Id = b.Id,
                Name = b.Name,
                ShortName = b.ShortName,
                // Specific to EntityB:
                BSpecificProperty1 = b.1,
                BSpecificProperty2 = b.2
            };
```

EntityA and EntityB both derive from a common base class that has the `Id`, `Name`, and `ShortName` properties. Same goes for `EntityASmall` and `EntityBSmall`. I have a lot of queries that look like this, so I'd like to make some sort of shorthand query that gets the common stuff out of the way first. I found a somewhat promising extension method that looks like this:

```
public static TSource SetCommonProperties<TSource>(this TSource input, EntityBaseClass entity, Action<TSource> updater) where TSource : EntitySmallBase
{
    input.Id = entity.Id;
    input.Name = entity.Name;
    input.ShortName = entity.Name;

    updater(input);

    return input;
}
```

I can use it like so:

```
var query = from a in EntityAs.AsEnumerable()
            select new EntityASmall().SetCommonProperties(a, x =>
            {
                ASpecificProperty1 = x.1;
                ASpecificProperty2 = x.2;
            });
```

Note the `AsEnumerable()`. Without it, I get "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree" which I'm guessing roughly means it's trying to convert the `Action` part to an expression for LINQ-to-SQL. Looks like the `AsEnumerable()` brings the collection locally where it works in full. Sorry for the long winded post, but is there any expression-y way to write this that will work with LINQ-to-SQL and Entity Framework? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `EntityAs` is an `IQueryable<>`?

Comment: Can't you write a generic method `ProjectOntoSmall` that takes a paremeter of a type `TEntity` and converts it to `TEntitySmall`? If you put constraints on these type parameters that they must derive from the base types, it would work, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make your code DRY, which is always good to put some effort in. Maybe you'll get your approach working with some toil and labour and some `Expression` voodoo, but maybe you're going to like this link: [Stop using AutoMapper in your Data Access Code](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code). (Even though you don't use AutoMapper).

By this nice piece of work you'll be able to write concise statements like:

```
context.EntityAs.Project().To<EntityASmall>();
context.EntityBs.Project().To<EntityBSmall>();
```

I've used this myself and I really like it.

Comment: Nice link. I like it, but unfortunately it doesn't help for anything but pretty simple mappings. I need something a little more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

The extension method you come up with looks ok.

Its just you have to create it for every derived entity and that could be fine in your case as you seem to have several dervied entities.

Secondly i dont think you really need to pass that action delegate there in your extension method.
Instead just call that method in there if possible . I dont know much about the design.

So your extension method would look like this

```
public static TSource SetCommonProperties<TSource>(this TSource input, EntityBaseClass entity)     where TSource : EntitySmallBase 
{ 
   input.Id = entity.Id; 
   input.Name = entity.Name; 
   input.ShortName = entity.Name; 

   this.Update(input); // Or this method could exist in any other class or static class.

  return input;
```

}

Then you can use the extesion method as follows as well.

```
var query = from a in EntityAs
        select new EntityASmall
        {      
            ASpecificProperty1      
            ASpecificProperty2    
        }).SetCommonProperties(a,entity)
```

This will eliminate your use of using AsEnumerable.
You can also transform from your base to derviced method with same method if you want like:

```
DerivceEntityObject SetCommonProperties(BaseEntity)
```

I hope this gives you an idea what i am trying to suggest here.

Comment: Hm, that works for LINQ-to-SQL, but not EF. It complains that SetCommonProperties can't be translated to SQL. I'm guessing it works in LINQ-to-SQL since the lines are a little more blurred between the LINQ-to-SQL and LINQ-to-Objects stuff.

Comment: Yes  I agree i missed that EF thing . It will complain cbecause it tries to translate the methods in SQL . In that case what you can do is remove this keywork (No more extension method) and use it as a normal method in the same way i mentioned.

Comment: e.g: for a in EntityAs Select SetCommonProperties(a,entity) and then takecare of the things as you are doing.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding, but if I were to do that I would have to write one of these methods for each type of entity which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: public static TSource SetCommonProperties<TSource>(TSource input, EntityBaseClass entity) where TSource : YouBaseClass

Comment: That would return `EntityA`, whereas I'm looking for `EntityASmall`. It also cannot be translated to SQL.

Comment: Dont use as Extension Method. It will always complain you for that.

Comment: just put the Method in after the select clause in your LINQ  and pass the references in there. That should help I hope . I have done this and there should be any problem with EF too.